# Inkfilepicker: Issue showing mobile version in iframe

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm trying to use "container" attribute pointing to iframe in mobile site version, but inkfilepicker sends desktop content in this case for both desktop and mobile devices. In attribute "container" is removed, I'm getting a new tab with mobile content. Please advice.

```
selectFilepickerService: function(service){
    var maxFilesize = $('#ufilepickContent form[name="filepickerConf"] input[name="max_file_size"]').val();
    this.lastService = service;
    filepicker.pick({
        mimetypes: ['image/*'],
        container: 'ufilepickService',
        maxSize  : maxFilesize,
        services : service
    }, $.proxy(function(fpfile){
        this.saveImage(fpfile.url, fpfile.filename);
    }, this));
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to force mobile mode by using mobile: true, for example

```
filepicker.pick({
    mimetypes: ['image/*'],
    container: 'ufilepickService',
    mobile: true,
    maxSize  : maxFilesize,
    services : service
}, $.proxy(function(fpfile){
    this.saveImage(fpfile.url, fpfile.filename);
}, this));
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! It would be great to have this thing mentioned in documentation as well.

Comment: I would also recommend adding this to the documentation